# Как записать результат FIND в переменную?

Tags: переменные, bat

мне нужно проверить идет ли работа в perfmon.
Для этого я создал этот код

```
logman | FIND "LnP" /c
```

Он выдает 1 если работает и 0 если нет.
Теперь я хочу сделать запрос IF по этому результату. Чтобы если работа не выполняеться то запустить ее.

```
is_running=logman | FIND "LnP" /c
if is_running EQU 0 goto :start_job
```

Но таким образом is_running не получает никакого значения. Подскажите пожалуйста что у меня не работает и как можно сделать нужную мне задачу.

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/batch_script/ Или даже https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Windows_Batch_Scripting

Comment: Полистал сам, богатый язык был в своё время, да... По второй ссылке есть всё, что вам нужно для исправления скрипта.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант 1. С помощью парсера:

```
for /f %%a in ('logman ^| FIND "LnP" /c') do set is_running=%%a

if "is_running" equ "0" goto start_job

goto end

:start_job

----Job procedure

goto end
```

Вариант 2. Если строка не найдена код ошибки больше 0

```
logman |FIND "LnP" /c

@if %ERRORLEVEL% GTR 0 goto start_job
```